# can Meteor flow-routing accept any parameters for it dynamic routing?

Tags: javascript, meteor, dynamic, flow-router

I use flow-routing on meteor.js

I want the template is like:

```
<template name="layout">
{{>header}}
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-2">
  {{>Template.dynamic template=sidebar}}
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  {{>Template.dynamic template=main para=message}}
</div>
</div>
{{>footer}}
</template>
```

Can I use router to make the parameter message like:

```
FlowRouter.notFound = {
// Subscriptions registered here don't have Fast Render support.
subscriptions: function() {

},
action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render('layout',{sidebar:'sidebar', main:'home',para='your input is wrong path.'})
}
};
```

How to pass the parameters into the dynamic template in flow-routing？

Answer (score 0):

You should have `para:'Your ...'`, not `para='Your ...'` (note the colon).